# Similar triangles, mistake or not?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, angle

Recently I had a problem with similar triangles. [The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCUw3.png)

Now, my teacher said that the triangles ABD and ACB are similar, but I was skeptical because I understood that the two angles of 30 degrees are congruent, but not the angle BAD (common angle). [I see the two triangles like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8us4.png)

Am I wrong or my teacher? Sorry if the problem is easy, but I really need to know if I'm wrong or not. Thank you for reading.

Comment: Your teacher should have said $\triangle ABD \sim \triangle ACB$ (instead of $\triangle ABC$). The order is important in this case, as evidenced by your justified confusion.

Comment: sorry that was my fault in writing the question, not of my teacher. So, my teacher is right?

Comment: Yes. The common angle is congruent to itself.

Comment: If $\angle CAB=73.6^\circ$, say, how big do you think is $\angle DAB$?

Comment: The same as CAB

Comment: Thank you so much. I needed to change my prospect of view and now I see that it is correct. Thank you